# Get Array from Page 1 and use it on Page 2 using on-Click (AngularJS)

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, node.js

hope you guys are kicking and jumping. Thanks for your usual understanding.

Frameworks: AngularJS, NodeJS

I am designing a login page. But the data to be compared with is an array of items in testData.html. I want to call the data on the login.html and compare it with user's input.

The login form works properly but the data is not read. I tried compiling the dataobject.html file separately, and it did not run.

I do not want to store this data in a .json file.
Later I will learn how to use the MongoDB to read data and compare
Please check the codes below.

[LOGIN.HTML]

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="loginCtrls" style="height:auto;">
    <form name="lForm">
          <div class="container">
            <label><b>Username</b></label>
            <input class="w3-round" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" ng-model="username" required>    
            <div align="right" style="width:550px;">&nbsp;
                <span style="color:red" ng-show="lForm.username.$dirty && lForm.username.$invalid">
                    <span ng-show = "lForm.username.$error.required">Username is required.</span>
                </span>         
            </div>

            <label><b>Password</b></label>
            <input class="w3-round" type="password" name="password" ng-model="password" placeholder="Password" required>
            <div align="right" style="width:550px;">&nbsp;
                <span style="color:red" ng-show="lForm.password.$dirty && lForm.password.$invalid">
                    <span ng-show = "lForm.password.$error.required">Password is required.</span>
                </span>         
            </div>

            <div align="center">
            <button class="w3-btn w3-teal w3-round" style="height:45px; width:100%; font-size:16px;" ng-disabled = "lForm.username.$dirty && lForm.username.$invalid || lForm.password.$dirty && lForm.password.$invalid" ng-click="chkData()">Click to Login</button>
            </div>
            <input type="checkbox" checked="checked"> Remember me
          </div>

          <div class="container" style="background-color:#f1f1f1; margin-top:0;">
            <span>Forgot <a href="#forgotpass.html">password?</a></span>
          </div>
    </form>
        <h4>{{result}} login attempt</h4>
</div>

<script src="js/loginCtrl.js"></script>
```

[LOGINCTRL.JS]

```
// JavaScript Document
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('loginCtrls', function($scope, $http) {

//get the file from the dataobject.html file
  $http.get("dataobject.html").then(function (response) {
    //parse the array object to $scope.users    
 $scope.users = response.data.records; 

  });

//this function checks the user's input and 
//compares it with the any match in object array
//the object array data has been passed into $scope.users
    $scope.chkData = function(){
        $scope.users = $scope.data.records;
         angular.forEach($scope.users, function(value, key){

             if(angular.equals(value.Username, $scope.username) && (value.Password, $scope.password)){
                $scope.result = "Successful ";//msg to be displayed
             }else {
                $scope.result = "Unsuccessful ";//msg to be displayed
             }
        });
    }
});
```

[DATA OBJECT.HTML]

```
<script src = "js/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="mdata">
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('mdata', function($scope) {
      $scope.data =  
      { "records":[ {"Username":"Alfreds","Password":"alfred","Session ID":"1"}, {"Username":"Ana","Password":"ana","Session ID":"2"}, {"Username":"Moreno","Password":"moreno","Session ID":"3"}] };
      });

});
</script>
```

Comment: weew you asking for a MITM attack. Go with auth0 and same yourself some time and effort

Comment: Okay, how do you do that? I am new to angular.

Comment: https://auth0.com/

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to do it using a service. Angular services are singletons. So, from one controller, you put the data in a service, switch pages, get the data from the service. 
NOTE: if user refreshes the page, the data in the service will be lost, as services (or angular for that matter) does not persist state.

ofc, everyone will have their own solution. I see you are a beginner, so the answer is meant to help you get a grasp of angular.

Comment: you are talking service... which? I am already using a service ($http) to call the data from dataobject.html page. Pls check the code for dataobject.html page above.

Comment: Create your own service. 
angular.module('yourModule').service('myService', myServiceFunc);
function myServiceFunc(){
var svc = this, logins =[];
svc.setData = setData;

function setData(data){
logins = data;
}
Something like this...

Answer (score 0):

You can store your data either on the $rootScope or by creating localStorage Services and u can access data anywhere in application but the best practices are creating some localStorage services.